# Can I change the GUI TTY?

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, lxdm

I installed Arch Linux on my friend's PC. He is used to the TTY 7 for running the graphical stuff on his system. But on Arch TTY 1 is for starting LXDM.

How can I move the graphical TTY from 1 to 7 or to something like 6?

Answer (score 3):

In default lxdm configuration file `/etc/lxdm/lxdm.conf` is a line:

```
arg=/usr/bin/X -background vt1
```

change `vt1` to `vt7` or any other terminal number.